Does clearing TPM from one OS remove stored keys from another OS?
If I clear TPM from GNU/Linux, will it remove the Windows BitLocker keys? And what if I clear it from the UEFI setup?

Are you asking if it will clear the BitLocker keys are you saying it will and asking if cleaning it from the UEFI setup will also clear the keys? What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

@Ramhound I was trying to see if my HDD could remain safe if I store my LUKS key in TPM and then enable Secure Boot and lock firmware to prevent someone from gaining access to my data. Looks like, at least in Windows, that the TPM store will only be accessible from the same OS. So I was wondering whether someone could clear the TPM keys on my system instead (for example, when it is out for repair).

@BlacklightMG: There is no "TPM store" generally speaking. In typical usage, the TPM only ever stores a single master key, sometimes two, which is not OS-dependent. Anything else "stored in TPM" becomes OS-specific because it is stored by the OS, not in the TPM.

If you clear the TPM, then you clear the TPM – it is the same device shared across all three systems.
Indeed that's why the UEFI settings screen even has the option: so that you could clear anything that some OS did to it.
(Technically speaking, the TPM doesn't store much – just 1–2 master encryption keys – while things like your BitLocker key are "sealed" and returned back to the OS for storage. But of course as soon as the TPM's keys are cleared, all of the "sealed" data becomes unusable anyway.)

If you need to clear the TPM be sure you suspend BitLocker before you do so, this will put the key on the disk, allowing you to continue to be protected by BitLocker
